# Are we allowed to send Pokéstop Submissions to Niantic?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was wondering if there was a way to send Pokéstop submissions?

There are 2 parks near my house that are fairly big and are not Pokéstops. While about 2km away there's another smaller park that is marked as a Pokéstop, so I wanted to ask Niantic if it was possible to make the other 2 parks a Pokéstop as well.

Also, was wondering how does Niantic identify all public parks and attractions? I can't find some of these Pokéstops on Google Maps. The most puzzling one was a tombstone-sized rock with a plaque marking the spot of a tree conservation area.

Comment: I don't think so.. but I'm not sure. Hopefully one of our other members can lend a helping hand

Comment: I'm hoping so. My family owns a martial arts dojo and it was a bit disheartening to find out that it's not a gym... I mean, that would be fitting, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This form has now been taken down.** I can see no substitute at this time, and I believe Niantic is not currently accepting new Pokestop submissions.

The below answer - in its original form - is obsolete.

---

You can submit new Pokestops using [this form](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=319928). Word of caution, while it *is* an official form, this is almost definitely subject to change, and is probably not going to be a stable link for long. It also may take quite a long time to process, given how much load they're probably under. (Someone poke me if this link no longer works.)

All Pokestops and gyms come from Niantic's previous game, Ingress, where users submitted tons and tons of places to become portals in that game. Niantic repurposed [the Ingress Intel Portal Map](https://www.ingress.com/intel) (you must have an Ingress account to view) for use in Pokemon Go.

Comment: This no longer works. Niantic removed the form.